# About the C* algebras $C_0(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete topology and consider the C* algebra $C_0(\mathbb{N})$. What is actually this space? Is it same as the space $c_0$ of all sequences that converge to zero?

Comment: Yes, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $C_0(X)$ is the set of continuous function in $X$ that vanishes in "$\infty$", i.e. $f \in C_0(X)$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$, exists a compact $K$ such that $|f|< \epsilon$ on $X\setminus K$.

Taking $\mathbb N = X$, we have that $C_0(\mathbb N)$ must be the set of sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, exists a compact set $K$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $|x_n| < \epsilon, \, \forall n \in \mathbb N \setminus K$.

What can you say about the compact subsets of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: They are just finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: so you get that that it is exactly $c_0$.

Comment: Yes I found it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you define $C_0(X)$ as the completion of the compactly supported continuous functions $X\to\Bbb{C}$ for the sup norm ?

Comment: @reuns this works if $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact as you can see in the following answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169584/completion-of-c-cx-with-respect-to-cdot-infty?rq=1

Comment: My question is how you define $C_0(X)$

Comment: $C_0(X) = \left \{ f: X \to \mathbb C : f \text{ continuous and for all } \epsilon > 0, \exists K \subset X \text{ compact  s.t. } |f(x)| < \epsilon, \, \forall x \in X\setminus K \right \}$.